# What did this code actually do?

Tags: c

In trying to fix a problem I accidentally put the following into my code.

```
/* simplified for context*/
char *command = NULL;
char *new_command = (char *) malloc(10);
 ...
free(command);
command = (char *) malloc (new_command + 1);
strcpy(command, new_command);
```

It not only complied it ran without problem, and even eliminated the original problem. I have since fixed the code to:

```
command = (char *) malloc (strlen(new_command) + 1);
```

which also works, but I would really like to understand why it worked before I fixed it and what exactly it was doing.

Edit: 
 Actually in the code left out with ... command was allocated and had data stored in it.
Both command and new_command had memory allocated and data stored in them prior to calling free. The were assigned in other functions, one originally came from a file that was read in and the other was received over TCP socket connection. The program matches the command from the client with the current exact executable including path from the file and then calls that command. Left all of that out to begin with because I didn't think it had anything to do with what happened, and why it worked at all with the incorrect call to malloc (passing a pointer instead of a size).

Comment: Is `free(command)` here a typo?

Comment: What were you trying to do, anyway?

Comment: You don't have to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: @DennisMeng free(command) isn't a typo. I had been using realloc but was unable to find figure out why it wasn't working so in desperation I freed the memory and redid the malloc. Badly the first time. I still don't know why the realloc didn't work and freeing and calling malloc again does work but it does.

Comment: @EdwardGoodson "so in desperation I freed the memory and redid the malloc" So...where were you allocating memory and getting `command` to point to it in the first place? That's what I'm wondering here.

Comment: Your `strlen(new_command)` is safe if the `...` code initializes `new_command` (but you should have mentioned that; the `...` isn't supposed to affect the workings of the code since you omitted it). If you're having problems with memory allocation ("`realloc()` isn't working"), then the chances are you are trampling out of bounds of memory somewhere else, and that is screwing everything up.  Use `valgrind` or a similar tool if you can.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, he could also have had `realloc` fail because of not having enough heap space...

Comment: Have you tried compiling your code using `gcc` or `clang` _WITHOUT_ the flag `-Wall`?

Comment: @DennisMeng: yes, it could be lack of space too — but I'd not be surprised to find memory access (writing) out of control given the confusion that reigns in the code shown.  I'm left wondering if the ill-formed `malloc()` was edited from a call to `realloc()` but the wrong argument was deleted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Huh, hadn't thought about that. It could very well be that the wrong argument got removed there (which would make a bit of sense if `new_command` was the pointer that was being passed into realloc)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I have been using valgrind, great program, and have eliminate almost all memory leaks. The one remaining is allocated as almost the first thing in the program and freed as the last. I assume some kind of memory corruption but after hours I can't find anything that writes out of bounds, no error on the free call on the pointer, the data being pointed to is always accessible, but valgrind says the memory from that malloc is lost. If valgrind can find memory corruption specifically, a reference to instructions on that function would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've got just one block left in use when the program exits, then you've done a stellar job releasing the memory — well done.  Usually, `valgrind` will spot memory abuses as the program is running — giving better reports if the program is compiled with debug information, but giving reports as best it can if not.  So, silence on memory abuses means you are probably not abusing dynamically allocated memory (`malloc()` et al), but doesn't rule out the possibility that you're abusing statically allocated memory or automatic memory (memory on 'the stack').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about `command = (char *) malloc (new_command + 1);`

In this call, the integer value of the `new_command` pointer is incremented by 1, and (probably quite a large area of) memory is allocated.

Assume `new_command` is a pointer to `0x00103456`. You're basically saying:

```
command = (char *) malloc( 0x00103456 + 1 );
```

or

```
command = (char *) malloc( 1061974 + 1 );
```

or

```
command = (char *) malloc( 1061975 );
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the only reason it runs without a problem is that it (most likely) a ludicrous amount of memory is allocated for `new_command`, but this is more by accident than by design.

Answer (score 6):

It should compile with lots of warnings.

If run, it should allocate an indeterminate but probably very large amount of memory with the second `malloc()` (based on the conversion of an address to a `size_t`) and then invoked horribly undefined behaviour by using `strcpy()` on memory which was never properly initialized.

Basically, the program, if run, should crash horribly.  But it might not — that's the beauty of undefined behaviour.  Anything is possible and it is OK because you invoked undefined behaviour.

Comment: You should have seen the original memory usage when I connected to it from my Erlang client - used 60% of his RAM, if this was the cause.

Comment: @CodyPoll: I could believe that the second memory allocation used 60% of RAM without much difficulty at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
 /* simplified for context*/
   char *command = NULL;
```

Declare a null pointer

```
   char *new_command = (char *) malloc(10);
```

Declare a pointer to a character array of `10` bytes

```
    ...
   free(command);
```

Free a null pointer. Should do nothing.

```
   command = (char *) malloc (new_command + 1);
```

Declare a pointer to a character array of `new_command + 1` bytes. The value of `new_command` is an address. So whatever address that is, plus `1`, is how many bytes you'd allocate. So if the address is `0x550000` it will allocate `0x550001` bytes.

```
   strcpy(command, new_command);
```

Copy bytes from `new_command` to `command` until a null (byte of `0`) is encountered. There's nothing pre-defined written into the `new_command` buffer (which has `10` bytes allocated to it). So if the code hits a byte of `0` before it accesses memory that doesn't belong to it, the program will run fine and copy over whatever junk is in the `new_command` buffer over to `command` up to that point. If it doesn't encounter a `0` before it gets into memory not belonging to it, it will die with a segmentation fault or similar error.

Comment: +1: Perfect detail, not just the remark "it's UB, anything could happen" :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're simply observing an artifact of **undefined behaviour** (for the last line).  Anything could have happened.

Comment: I disagree that the penultimate line is ill-defined. The expression `new_command + 1` will be automatically cast to a `size_t`. Although `malloc` will probably be called with a ludicrous value, it's behavior is still well defined.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm not the downvoter, but your statement by itself doesn't really help the poster. If the poster doesn't know which part is UB, this won't help him avoid it in the future.

Comment: @DennisMeng: My assumption was that the OP already knows this is "dodgy" and wanted to know how it could still have worked.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: Ah, I misread the code.  I read it as `new_command[1]`.  So indeed, the penultimate line is not UB.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Do you consider `malloc(rand())` UB? I don't think so because `malloc` is defined for any input. Or if you really want to be pedantic, you might consider _any_ call to `malloc` UB because it's return value is always indeterminate (either a valid, arbitrary memory address, or `NULL`).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I guess I'm used to being more explicit, just in case. (For example, if the poster thought it was dodgy for other reasons, and didn't consider what you were thinking at all)

Comment: @SchighSchagh: As I said, I misread the code ;)  (But the output of `rand()` is not considered indeterminate in the C standard, whereas the contents of freshly `malloc`ed memory is...)